# How Can I Connect a TAP to Ethernet?

Tags: networking, network-interface, tap

I am trying to set up a Linux bridge to connect a physical radio (N210) to ns3 via a TAP. The radio is plugged into Ethernet (epn0s25) and I have tried the following console commands:

```
sudo brctl addbr bridge0
sudo tunctl -t tap0
sudo ifconfig tap0 hw ether 00:00:00:00:00:01
sudo ifconfig tap0 0.0.0.0 up
sudo brctl addif bridge0 tap0
sudo brctl addif bridge0 epn0s25
sudo ifconfig mybridge 10.1.1.1 netmask 255.255.255.0 up
```

However pinging epn0s25 or bridge0 results in no activity on the other side. `showstp` on bridge0 shows tap0 is disabled so I think that may be the problem but I am unsure how to fix it.

Comment: I'm stuck in the same boat; for a moment I thought I needed to create a nmcli ethernet adapter using tap0 as the device - buut that doesn't seem to work- between network manager, brctl, and iptools2, i dont really understand what the heck

Comment: @ThorSummoner A `tap` interface is one end of an application which processes network packets. Which application do you plan to connect to the tap interface? The question looks a bit like you are trying to do something else, what exactly is your goal? Is `ns3` a network namespace? If yes, what prevents you from just moving `epn0s25` into the network namespace?

Comment: @dirkt I was hoping to attach NetworkManager to tap0 so my host could communicate over the bridge. HostA has eth0 and 10gbe eth1, where eth1 is a link to a single HostB, I want HostB to be on the same network as HostA, (currently I am nat'ing HostB into the network via HostA). so eth0 and eth1 are bridged, HostA has tap0. What does it take to connect HostA to the network (without a loopback cable since I dont have a pair of 10ge interfaces to phyisically loop back into HostA)

Comment: @ThorSummoner: Sorry, something is very confused here. NetworkManager manages the interfaces, it certainly isn't the endpoint of any tap-interface. Endpoints of tap interfaces are tunnels like OpenVPN, virtual machines, etc. Also, your situation seems to different from the one in this question. Please make a new question, describe your situation in detail (what do you mean by "HostA *has* tap0"? Did you create it there? Can you draw a diagram of your network?). You can ping me in the comments. If you just want HostA and HostB to be in the same network, a simple bridge is enough.

Comment: *groan* I think all my issues have been NetworkManager bugs, or "features" as it-were; basically I dont think network manager can do bridges yet (in ubuntu 16.04), using /etc/network/interfaces (a la https://wiki.debian.org/BridgeNetworkConnections#Configuring_bridging_in_.2Fetc.2Fnetwork.2Finterfaces)  and `sudo ifup br0`, it worked the first time, no issues

Answer (score 1):

You need to give the tap the IP address. Or, if it's the host end of a virtual machine interface, then you would rather give the IP address to the virtual machine interface.